# Iterate a function through every subfolder

Tags: bash, loops, unix, syntax, subdirectory

I have a function that takes a file, does some operation, and creates a bunch of output files.
I have 100 subfolders named:

```
d066, d067, d068.... d165, d166
```

Each of them has only 1 file. What I want to do is go into each subfolder, grab the name of the file, apply the function to it, leave the subfolder, enter the next one and so on.

I wrote this script:

```
for i in {60..166}; do
    
    if [ $i -lt 100 ];
    then 
        var2=d0$i
    else
        var2=d$i
    fi             
    cd $var2 || exit             
    f=$(find . -type f)   
    gd2e.py -rnxFile $f   
    cd ..                
    
done
```

The issue is that my code gets out of the folder containing the subfolder, and stops. Does anyone knows of a better way to do this ?

Comment: Please add a suitable shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) and then paste your script at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: So far it looks like the spell mistakes I made were responsible for it not working. 
Thank you @markp-fuso for the faster way of doing it ! It also works nicely.

I'd like to chose your comment as an answer but since you only commented I don't have the option to accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the function can work with a directoy as part of the input parameter (eg, `gd2e.py -rnxFile ${i}/${f}`), a few ideas to streamline the current code:

```
while read -r f
do
    gd2e.py -rnxfFile "${f}"
done < <(find d{060..166} -type f)
```

If the `d{060..166}` directories can have subdirectories that you don't want to scan we can add a `-maxdepth 1` to the `find`:

```
while read -r f
do
    gd2e.py -rnxfFile "${f}"
done < <(find d{060..166} -maxdepth 1 -type f)
```